# Blog URL Crashes Internet Explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, crash

I have a blog through Blogger - http://www.concertexperiencepeeps.com. Whenever I try to view my blog through Internet Explorer it crashes the page and will not allow me to view it. It works fine on Safari though. I cannot figure out why. Any ideas would be appreciated. Thanks@!

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought, but did you try taking the special lightning (⚡) symbols out, at least from the title tags?